# Remove cite from table of contents

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, citing

I want to put a citation in the section title

```
\section{AAAB \cite{KK} }
```

But i only want this cite to appear in the text but not on the page of contents. How to remove cite from table of contents ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the optional argument of the `\section` command:

```
\section[TOC Entry]{In text entry\cite{KK}}
```